# Heroku + Rails + GeoIp = uninitialized constant GeoIP error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-2, geoip

I'm trying to deploy my old website to the Heroku.
Everything goes well, it starts, but when I access it through a web browser i get

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicantsController::GeoIP):
```

I'm using Rails 2.3.18 (my website is very simple and just want to deploy it "as it is" and asap; on dedicated server everything worked well).

I have a GeoIP.dat file in 'db' folder and in controllers/applicants_controller.rb I have

```
line 32:    geoip ||= GeoIP.new("db/GeoIP.dat")
line 33:    location = geoip.country('google.com')
```

If I launch irb on Heroku everything looks good:

```
login@sancho:~$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.7785
~ $ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'geoip'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> geoip ||= GeoIP.new("db/GeoIP.dat")
=> #<GeoIP:0x00000002b3a6a8 @mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000002b3a680>, @flags=0, @database_type=1, @record_length=3, @file=#<File:db/GeoIP.dat>, @database_segments=[16776960]>
irb(main):004:0> geoip.country('google.com')
=> #<struct GeoIP::Country request="google.com", ip="74.125.228.110", country_code=225, country_code2="US", country_code3="USA", country_name="United States", continent_code="NA">
irb(main):005:0>
```

Here is full error log.

```
2013-05-02T13:08:25.938481+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing ApplicantsController#create (for 87.207.27.219 at 2013-05-02 13:08:25) [POST]
2013-05-02T13:08:25.938481+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"status"=>"complete"}
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant ApplicantsController::GeoIP):
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:131:in `rescue in const_missing'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `block in perform_action_with_benchmark'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `block in call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:120:in `const_missing'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `block in build_middleware_stack'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/applicants_controller.rb:32:in `create'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `perform_action'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.029730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030057+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.18/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2013-05-02T13:08:26.030750+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendering /app/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Bundle log from Heroku:

```
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   The source :gemcutter is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
   Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
   Using rake (0.8.7)
   Using activesupport (2.3.18)
   Using rack (1.1.6)
   Using actionpack (2.3.18)
   Using actionmailer (2.3.18)
   Using activerecord (2.3.18)
   Using activeresource (2.3.18)
   Using daemons (1.1.9)
   Using eventmachine (1.0.3)
   Using geoip (1.2.1)
   Using pg (0.15.1)
   Using rails (2.3.18)
   Using thin (1.5.1)
   Using bundler (1.3.2)
   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I forgot to edit config/boot.rb and create edit/preinitializer.rb as described here http://gembundler.com/v1.3/rails23.html